# How to show popover on didSelect of table view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

[image]

*I want to implement this type of view on my tableview did select. This is a iOS project using swift programming.. the effect is similer to whatsapp ios app...*

> can any one have any suggestion how this can be done on a Table view
>   cell ?

Comment: Which popover you are using ?

Comment: Just pass the sender to the popover on didSelect

Comment: I am not using anything ... i want to implement it !

Comment: Install any popover via pods and on didSelect pass the sender to the popover. It will work

Comment: you have use third party by cocoapods you can them github.

Comment: @MRizwan33 No need to use a third party lib, UIMenuController class is for that. Please see posted answer

Answer (score 2):

This tooltip actually has a name, `UIMenuController`, and can be customized and used in your own app:

```
class ResponsiveView: UIView {
    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var responsiveView: ResponsiveView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        responsiveView = ResponsiveView()

        // Add our responsive view to a super view
        responsiveView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50)
        responsiveView.center = self.view.center
        responsiveView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 124.0/255.0, green: 112.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        responsiveView.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
        responsiveView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.view.addSubview(responsiveView)

        // Add a long press gesture recognizer to our responsive view
        responsiveView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let longPressGR = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressHandler))
        longPressGR.minimumPressDuration = 0.3 // how long before menu pops up
        responsiveView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGR)
    }

    @objc func longPressHandler(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        guard sender.state == .began,
            let senderView = sender.view,
            let superView = sender.view?.superview
            else { return }

        // Make responsiveView the window's first responder
        senderView.becomeFirstResponder()

        // Set up the shared UIMenuController
        let saveMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Save", action: #selector(saveTapped))
        let deleteMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Delete", action: #selector(deleteTapped))
        UIMenuController.shared.menuItems = [saveMenuItem, deleteMenuItem]

        // Tell the menu controller the first responder's frame and its super view
        UIMenuController.shared.setTargetRect(senderView.frame, in: superView)

        // Animate the menu onto view
        UIMenuController.shared.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
    }

    @objc func saveTapped() {
        print("save tapped")
        // ...
        // This would be a good place to optionally resign
        // responsiveView's first responder status if you need to
        responsiveView.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    @objc func deleteTapped() {
        print("delete tapped")
        // ...
        responsiveView.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: how to use it ?@Harshal

Comment: I don't your will give exact what he wants. but it looks good @RahulSinghaRoy you should try.

Comment: @RahulSinghaRoy, Please try this repository https://github.com/harshal-wani/UITableViewCell-Tooltip

Answer (score 0):

```
func menuPopup(index:IndexPath){
 var menuController = UIMenuController.shared
        let actionOneMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Action1", action: #selector(actionOne))
        let actionTwoMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Action1", action: #selector(actionTwo))
        let actionThreeMenuItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Action3", action: #selector(actionThree))
        menuController.isMenuVisible = true
        menuController.arrowDirection = .default
        let rect = contactsTableView.rectForRow(at: index)
        menuController.setTargetRect(rect, in: contactsTableView)
        menuController.menuItems = [actionOneMenuItem, actionTwoMenuItem,actionThreeMenuItem]
        menuController.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)
    }

    @objc func actionOne(){

    }
    @objc func actionTwo(){

    }
    @objc func actionThree(){

    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool{
        return true
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        contactsTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        tableView.becomeFirstResponder()
        menuPopup(index: indexPath)
    }
```